# Ms Access, parameterized queries, What is wrong with this code?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I like to use a parameterized query to access a PostreSQL Database with ADO/Ms Access.

```
'sql-statement: SELECT id, str FROM tbl WHERE str LIKE '<userstring>';
'str is character varying in the DB

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con 'connection is open
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, str FROM tbl WHERE str LIKE @FirstParameter"
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@FirstParameter", adVarWChar, adParamInput)
param1.Value = userstring
cmd.Parameters.Append param1 ' ERROR
```

I have to translate the error: "The parameter-object is not set properly. Inconsitent or invalid."

Comment: You can connect to a PostgreSQL Database by using the ADO library and MS Access as Userinterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO uses question marks to indicate parameters. Likely, using your combination of provider and parameter indicator, the parameter is not recognized.

Postgresql uses dollarsigns to indicate parameters using the [`PREPARE ... EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html) syntax, but that requires you to pass the parameters again (with questionmarks) in the `EXECUTE` clause, so I don't recommend that

Unfortunately I don't have a postgresql setup handy, but try the following:

```vb
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con 'connection is open
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, str FROM tbl WHERE str LIKE ?"
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarWChar, adParamInput, Len(userstring), userstring) 'Unnamed parameter
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The first (unnamed parameter) is working well. The second results in a error: "There is no parameter $1. While executing the query". I think it is a postgreSQL error.

Comment: Yes, I was sort-of expecting that since Postgres uses a more explicit `Prepare` and `Execute` syntax for prepared statements with the dollarsigns. I'll remove that one.